# Python throwing error in reading JSON file

Tags: python, json

I am writing a function in a Python Script which will read the json file and print it.

The scripts reads as:

```
def main(conn):
    global link, link_ID
    with open('ad_link.json', 'r') as statusFile:
        status = json.loads(statusFile.read())
        statusFile.close()
        print(status)
        link_data = json.load[status]
        link = link_data["link"]
        link_ID = link_data["link_id"]
   print(link)
   print(link_ID)
```

I am getting error as:

```
link_data = json.load[status]
TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable
```

What is the issue?

**The content of ad_link.json** The file I am receiving is saved in this manner.

```
"{\"link\": \"https://res.cloudinary.com/dnq9phiao/video/upload/v1534157695/Adidas-Break-Free_nfadrz.mp4\", \"link_id\": \"ad_Bprise_ID_Adidas_0000\"}"
```

**The function to receive and write JSON file**

```
def on_message2(client, userdata, message):
    print("New MQTT message received. File  %s line %d" % (filename, cf.f_lineno))
    print("message received?/'/'/'  ", str(message.payload.decode("utf-8")), \
      "topic", message.topic, "retained ", message.retain)
    global links
    links = str(message.payload.decode("utf-8")
    logging.debug("Got new mqtt message as %s" % message.payload.decode("utf-8"))
    status_data = str(message.payload.decode("utf-8"))
    print(status_data)
    print("in function on_message2")
    with open("ad_link.json", "w") as outFile:
        json.dump(status_data, outFile)   
    time.sleep(3)
```

**The output of this function**

```
New MQTT message received. File C:/Users/arunav.sahay/PycharmProjects/MediaPlayer/venv/Include/mediaplayer_db_mqtt.py line 358
message received?/'/'/'   {"link": "https://res.cloudinary.com/dnq9phiao/video/upload/v1534157695/Adidas-Break-Free_nfadrz.mp4", "link_id": "ad_Bprise_ID_Adidas_0000"} topic ios_push retained  1
{"link": "https://res.cloudinary.com/dnq9phiao/video/upload/v1534157695/Adidas-Break-Free_nfadrz.mp4", "link_id": "ad_Bprise_ID_Adidas_0000"}
```

**EDIT**

I found out the error is in JSON format. I am receiving the JSON data in a wrong format. How will I correct that?

Comment: what are you trying to do in this line "link_data = json.load[status]"?

Comment: can you paste your content of ad_link.json?

Comment: `json.loads(statusFile.read())` returns dictionary not int

Comment: 1) `status` is **already a Python object** loaded from JSON. You don't need to try to load it again. Just use the object as a dictionary or list directly. 2) You don't need to call `statusFile.close()`, the `with` statement already handles closing for you. 3) Use `json.load(statusFile)` and have the `json` module do the reading (it can then be free to be more efficient for larger documents and not read the whole document into memory in one go when that's not even needed).

Comment: Right, so you can drop the `json.load[...]` line altogether, and just use `status['link']` and `status['link_id']`.

Comment: it seems json.dumps is converting again to already converted json. you can avoid that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two major errors here:

1. You are trying to use the `json.load` function as a sequence or dictionary mapping. It's a function, you can only call it; you'd use `json.load(file_object)`. Since `status` is actually a string, you'd have to use `json.loads(status)` to actually decode a JSON document stored in a string.
2. In `on_message2`, you encoded JSON data to JSON *again*. Now you have to decode it *twice*. That's an unfortunate waste of computer resources.

In the `on_message2` function, the `message.payload` object is a bytes-value containing a UTF-8 encoded JSON document, if you want to write that to a file, don't decode to text, and don't encode the text to JSON again. Just write those bytes *directly* to a file:

```
def on_message2(client, userdata, message):
    logging.debug("Got new mqtt message as %s" % message.payload.decode("utf-8"))
    with open("ad_link.json", "wb") as out:
        out.write(message.payload)
```

Note the `'wb'` status; that opens a file in *binary mode* for writing, at which point you can write the `bytes` object to that file.

When you open a file without a `b` in the mode, you open a file in *text mode*, and when you write a text string to that file object, Python encodes that text to bytes for you. The default encoding depends on your OS settings, so without an explicit `encoding` argument to `open()` you can't even be certain that you end up with UTF-8 JSON bytes again! Since you already *have* a bytes value, there is no need to manually decode then have Python encode again, so use a binary file object and avoid that decode / encode dance here too.

You can now load the file contents with `json.load()` without having to decode again:

```
def main(conn):
    with open('ad_link.json', 'rb') as status_file:
        status = json.load(status_file)
    link = status["link"]
    link_id = status["link_id"]
```

Note that I opened the file as binary again. As of Python 3.6, the `json.load()` function can work both with binary files and text files, and for binary files it can auto-detect if the JSON data was encoded as UTF-8, UTF-16 or UTF-32.\

If you are using Python 3.5 or earlier, open the file as text, but do explicitly set the encoding to UTF-8:

```
def main(conn):
    with open('ad_link.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as status_file:
        status = json.load(status_file)
    link = status["link"]
    link_id = status["link_id"]
```

Comment: Oh! thank you so much. It worked. I understood where the problem was and what actually is happening in the process. Well written. Appreciate it! (y)

Answer (score 0):

replace [loads](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.loads) with [load](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.load) when dealing with file object which supports read like operation

```
 def main(conn):
        global link, link_ID
        with open('ad_link.json', 'r') as statusFile:
            status = json.load(statusFile)
            status=json.loads(status)               
            link = status["link"]
            link_ID = status["link_id"]
       print(link)
       print(link_ID)
```

Comment: `status` is probably a more complex object, either a list or a dictionary with one of the values a dictionary with `link` and `link_id` keys.

Comment: It throws: TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: status might be a list of dicts then try status[0]["link"]

Comment: @THEBUSINESSDIARIES: that would indicate that `statusFile` does **not** contain a JSON object. Did you double-encode the data perhaps?

Comment: @mad_: no, `status` is clearly a string, not a list. They appear to have a double-encoded JSON document.

Comment: yup I can see that too. may be he has posted here something else and using some other string format with`[` and `]` in the file

Comment: sorry .. I posted something else ... "{\"link\": \"https://res.cloudinary.com/dnq9phiao/video/upload/v1534157695/Adidas-Break-Free_nfadrz.mp4\", \"link_id\": \"ad_Bprise_ID_Adidas_0000\"}"    this is what I am receiving

Comment: @MartijnPieters It is a valid string as posted by OP with double encoding. It has something to do with how it is present in the file

Comment: @THEBUSINESSDIARIES: right, so you have **double encoded** JSON data. Decode it *again*. `with open('ad_link.json', 'r') as statusFile: status = json.loads(json.load(statusFile))`. (or, and this is the better option, *fix the code that double encodes*).

Comment: Yup we have to double encode to get the dict. Updated the answer. @MartijnPieters is right if possible correct the json else do two times encoding

Comment: @THEBUSINESSDIARIES: so `message.payload` is a JSON document. Don't decode it, don't use `json.dump()`, just write it directly to a file opened in binary mode.

Comment: the error is mainly ..because of the JSON file writing .. how will I solve that

Comment: @THEBUSINESSDIARIES It is okay just to brief you the first encoding is actually converting it to a unicode string which is still a string and second encoding is what is actually converting it to usable dict object unless you change the original json string

Answer (score 0):

```
def main(conn):
    global link, link_ID
    with open('ad_link.json', 'r') as statusFile:
        link_data = json.loads(statusFile.read())
        link = link_data["link"]
        link_ID = link_data["link_id"]
        print(link)
        print(link_ID)
```

Comment: can you describe what this code does and why does it solve the issue?

Comment: **json_loads** return the python dict, so you can manipulate this dict to get the value you want